# Нужно разрабатывать страницу для отображения данных по критериям

Tags: python, django

Я пока новичок в django. Поэтому можете дать совет что прочитать или где поискать. Как разработать страницу, чтобы данные из БД можно было отфлиртовать по значениям и т.п.?

Comment: Документация на русском - https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/

Comment: актуальная официальная документация на английском - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/

Comment: MDN - сам доку переводил пару лет назад (может уже отредактировали). Там все просто и ясно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для фильтрации в админке - смотрите доку

Для фильтрации не а админке - изучайте GET/POST запросы, еще можно Ajax выучить. Остальное - Django

Если кратко - то передаете через запросы то, что нужно отфильтровать.

Пример для GET запроса:

```
# localhost:8000/page-list/?value=404

def request(request, *args, **kwargs):
    object_list = SomeModel.objects.all()
    if 'GET' in request.method:
        if 'value' in request.GET and request.GET['value']:
            object_list = object_list.filter(value=request.GET['value'])
    ...
    return render(.....)
```

---

По запросам

GET-запросы - это передача параметров в самом url. Параметры указываются после `?` в формате `<ключ>=<значение>`. Если необходимо передать несколько параметров - то пары ключ-значение разделяются знаком `&`.

```
http://www.google.com/?q=Get%20запросы&lang=ru
# q -> "Get запросы"
# lang -> "ru"

https://localhost/somepage/?search=asdaf&filter_year=2019&order_by=asc
# search -> "asdaf"
# filter_year -> "2019"
# order_by -> "asc"
```

GET можно использовать, если передаете параметры, знание о которых не позволит собрать персональную информацию или узнать другие данные, о которых другим лучше не знать (пароли и тп)

POST запросы - это почти как GET, но данные передаются не через адрес запроса. Wikipedia гласит

> Метод запроса POST предназначен для запроса, при котором веб-сервер принимает данные, заключённые в тело сообщения, для хранения. Он часто используется для загрузки файла или представления заполненной веб-формы.

Данные переданные таким запросом не отобразятся в логах, и позволяет передать много больше информации, чем GET

Из минусов - при применении фильтра элементов с его помощью, при попытке обновить страницу будет всплывать предупреждении об отправке данных формы

AJAX - Это способ отправки запросов. Юзается через JavaScript и его производные (jQuery и остальные фреймворки/библиотеки). Он решает проблему POST запроса. Можно отправить любые запросы, главное знать как.ъ

Пример, как он работает:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('#content');

  $.ajax({
    method: 'get', // или 'post'
    url: '/somepage',
    data: 'value=404',
    success: function(data) {
      cnt.html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  No ajax
</div>
<button id="btn">Send request via Ajax</button>
```

Пример здесь не сработает, ибо "Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован", но в пределах одного сервера это сработает.

Остальное, про GET и POST параметры прочтете в доке по Django :)

Comment: а есть где еще больше информации именно про запросы и их отображения и т.п.?

Comment: да в поисковике это быстро ищется. ща добавлю информацию по запросам